# Is there any approach for encrypting mysql column by key?

Tags: mysql, php, transparent-data-encryption, computed-column

I have a scenario for encrypting user information in mysql db. Is there any approach to encrypting column by key. This key information will be there in application configuration file. This key we won't store any where in databases/triggers.

My approach is while connecting to database from application we'll pass key. With that key we'll get the information. If some user directly comes into db he will see the encrypted data in table columns.

Please suggest how can I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [encryption/decryption functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html). For example, using AES (see [aes_encrypt](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt)):

```
SET @key_str = SHA2('My secret passphrase',512);
SET @crypt_str = AES_ENCRYPT('text',@key_str);
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(@crypt_str,@key_str);
```

Which gives, as expected:

```
+----------------------------------+
| AES_DECRYPT(@crypt_str,@key_str) |
+----------------------------------+
| text                             |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So you can store the result from `AES_ENCRYPT` in the column, and then retrieve it using `AES_DECRYPT`.

The above code is also compatible with MariaDB (at least 10.2). MySQL additionally supports an init string to the `AES_ENCRYPT` and `AES_DECRYPT` functions, see the example at the link to `AES_ENCRYPT` above.

MySQL also offers [InnoDB tablespace encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-tablespace-encryption.html), but that will encrypt the whole table, not just individual columns.

Comment: I suggest that the line with `SHA2` adds nothing other than making the `key_string` harder to type, _not harder to hack_.

Comment: The `AES_*` functions date back at least to MySQL 5.0.